# Configuring WebLogic Logging for Commons Logging

Tags: oracle, logging, weblogic, apache-commons-logging

I'm writing a Spring web application deployed to a WebLogic 10.3.3 server. I've tried to enable logging as described by the Oracle documentation here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14571_01/web.1111/e13739/config_logs.htm#WLLOG154

Both commons-logging-1.1.1.jar and com.bea.core.weblogic.commons.logging_1.4.0.0.jar are placed in the lib folder of the WebLogic domain, and I'm attempting to initialize the logger exactly as described in the Oracle example. I see the following exception in the server console:

> Caused by: org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: The chosen 
>   LogFactory implementation does not extend LogFactory. Please check your 
>   configuration. (Caused by java.lang.ClassCastException:weblogic.logging.commons.LogFactoryImpl)

Does anyone know of any possible solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Works for me. Seems like a classloader issue. 
Check whether another commons-logging lib is not loaded before application provided commons-logging.